# Find date range overlaps within the same table, for specific user MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, alias, intervals

I am by no means an MySQL expert, so I am looking for any help on this matter.

I need to perform a simple test (in principle), I have this (simplified) table:

```
tableid | userid  | car      | From        | To
--------------------------------------------------------
1       | 1       |  Fiesta  |  2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31
2       | 1       |  MX5     |  2015-02-01 | 2015-02-28
3       | 1       |  Navara  |  2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31
4       | 1       |  GTR     |  2015-03-28 | 2015-04-30
5       | 2       |  Focus   |  2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31
6       | 2       |  i5      |  2015-02-01 | 2015-02-28
7       | 2       |  Aygo    |  2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31
8       | 2       |  206     |  2015-03-29 | 2015-04-30
9       | 1       |  Skyline |  2015-04-29 | 2015-05-31
10      | 2       |  Skyline |  2015-04-29 | 2015-05-31
```

I need to find two things here:

1. If any user has date overlaps in his car assignments of more than one day (end of the assignment can be on the same day as the new assignment start).
2. Did any two users tried to get the same car assigned on the same date, or the date ranges overlap for them on the same car.

So the query (or queries) I am looking for should return those rows:

```
tableid | userid  | car      | From        | To
--------------------------------------------------------
3       | 1       |  Navara  |  2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31
4       | 1       |  GTR     |  2015-03-28 | 2015-04-30
7       | 2       |  Aygo    |  2015-03-01 | 2015-03-31
8       | 2       |  206     |  2015-03-29 | 2015-04-30
9       | 1       |  Skyline |  2015-04-29 | 2015-05-31
10      | 2       |  Skyline |  2015-04-29 | 2015-05-31
```

I feel like I am bashing my head against the wall here, I would be happy with being able to do these comparisons in separate queries. I need to display them in one table but I could always then join the results.

I've done research and few hours of testing but I cant get nowhere near the result I want.

[SQLFiddle with the above test data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3fe7/1)

I've tried these posts btw (they were not exactly what I needed but were close enough, or so I thought):

[Comparing two date ranges within the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579844/comparing-two-date-ranges-within-the-same-table)

[How to compare values of text columns from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938064/how-to-compare-values-of-text-columns-from-the-same-table)

This was the closest solution I could find but when I tried it on a single table (joining table to itself) I was getting crazy results: [Checking a table for time overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571538/checking-a-table-for-time-overlap)

**EDIT**

As a temporary solution I have adapted a different approach, similar to the posts I have found during my research (above). I will now check if the new car rental / assignment date overlaps with any date range within the table. If so I will save the id(s) of the rows that the date overlaps with. This way at least I will be able to flag overlaps and allow a user to look at the flagged rows and to resolve any overlaps manually.

Thanks to everyone who offered their help with this, I will flag philipxy answer as the chosen one (in next 24h) unless someone has better way of achieving this. I have no doubt that following his answer I will be able to eventually reach the results I need. At the moment though I need to adopt any solution that works as I need to finish my project in next few days, hence the change of approach.

**Edit #2**

The both answers are brilliant and to anyone who finds this post having the same issue as I did, read them both and look at the fiddles! :) A lot of amazing brain-work went into them! Temporarily I had to go with the solution I mention in #1 Edit of mine but I will be adapting my queries to go with @Ryan Vincent approach + @philipxy edits/comments about ignoring the initial one day overlap.

Comment: I have followed the philipxy reply but up to now I have failed to produce anything solid. By no means I say that philipxy answer is wrong, I think I just wasn't able to get my head around my own data. If you have an answer for this please do share it. Thanks!

Comment: The queries: [Overlapping cars by user... SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/5). Also: [More than one user in a car at the same time. SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/7).

Comment: You can upvote any answers you find useful - so feel free to do that with other answers you found helpful such as `philipxy` It is appreciated. There is a lot of good advice there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the first part: Overlapping cars per user...

[SQLFiddle - correlated Query and Join Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/5)

Second part - more than one user in one car at the same time: [SQLFiddle - correlated Query and Join Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/7). Query below...

I use the correlated queries:

You will likely need indexes on userid and 'car'. However - please check the 'explain plan' to see how it mysql is accessing the data. And just try it :)

**Overlapping cars per user**

The query:

```
SELECT `allCars`.`userid`  AS `allCars_userid`, 
       `allCars`.`car`     AS `allCars_car`, 
       `allCars`.`From`    AS `allCars_From`, 
       `allCars`.`To`      AS `allCars_To`,
       `allCars`.`tableid` AS `allCars_id`
 FROM  
       `cars` AS `allCars`
 WHERE 
     EXISTS  
         (SELECT 1       
          FROM `cars` AS `overlapCar`            
          WHERE 
               `allCars`.`userid` = `overlapCar`.`userid` 
           AND `allCars`.`tableid` <> `overlapCar`.`tableid`          
           AND NOT (   `allCars`.`From`  >= `overlapCar`.`To`      /* starts after outer ends  */  
                    OR `allCars`.`To`    <= `overlapCar`.`From`))  /* ends before outer starts */
 ORDER BY
        `allCars`.`userid`, 
        `allCars`.`From`, 
        `allCars`.`car`;
```

The results:

```
allCars_userid  allCars_car  allCars_From  allCars_To  allCars_id  
--------------  -----------  ------------  ----------  ------------
             1  Navara       2015-03-01    2015-03-31             3
             1  GTR          2015-03-28    2015-04-30             4
             1  Skyline      2015-04-29    2015-05-31             9
             2  Aygo         2015-03-01    2015-03-31             7
             2  206          2015-03-29    2015-04-30             8
             2  Skyline      2015-04-29    2015-05-31            10
```

*Why it works? or How I think about it:*

I use the correlated query so I don't have duplicates to deal with and it is probably the easiest to understand for me. There are other ways of expressing the query. Each has advantages and drawbacks. I want something I can easily understand.

Requirement: For each user ensure that they don't have two or more cars at the same time.

So, for each user record (AllCars) check the complete table (overlapCar) to see if you can find a *different* record that overlaps for the time of the current record. If we find one then select the current record we are checking (in allCars).

Therefore the *overlap* check is:

- the `allCars` `userid` and the `overLap` `userid` must be the same
- the `allCars` car record and the `overlap` car record *must be different*
- the `allCars` time range and the `overLap` time range  must overlap.

  *The time range check:*

  Instead of checking for overlapping times use positive tests. The easiest approach, is to check it doesn't overlap, and apply a `NOT` to it.

**One car with More than One User at the same time...**

The query:

```
SELECT  `allCars`.`car`     AS `allCars_car`,
        `allCars`.`userid`  AS `allCars_userid`,  
        `allCars`.`From`    AS `allCars_From`, 
        `allCars`.`To`      AS `allCars_To`, 
        `allCars`.`tableid` AS `allCars_id`
        
 FROM  
       `cars` AS `allCars`
 WHERE 
     EXISTS  
        (SELECT 1       
         FROM `cars` AS `overlapUser`            
         WHERE 
              `allCars`.`car` = `overlapUser`.`car` 
          AND `allCars`.`tableid` <> `overlapUser`.`tableid`          
          AND NOT (    `allCars`.`From`  >= `overlapUser`.`To`       /* starts after outer ends  */  
                   OR  `allCars`.`To`    <= `overlapUser`.`From`))  /* ends before outer starts */
 ORDER BY
        `allCars`.`car`,      
        `allCars`.`userid`, 
        `allCars`.`From`;
```

The results:

```
allCars_car  allCars_userid  allCars_From  allCars_To    allCars_id  
-----------  --------------  ------------  ----------  ------------
Skyline                   1  2015-04-29    2015-05-31             9
Skyline                   2  2015-04-29    2015-05-31            10
```

*Edit:*

In view of the comments, by @philipxy , about time ranges needing 'greater than or equal to' checks I have updated the code here. I havn't changed the `SQLFiddles`.

Comment: Oh my god Ryan, as much as philipxy answer thought me great deal about logic when creating the queries (and this is knowledge I will be able to use for writing any queries in the future now) your answer is so brilliantly easy to understand that I am quite frankly gobsmacked. You have actually help me look and understand my own data in better way. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PawelKosi, Was interesting to do. Glad to help. :)

Comment: I would not ordinarily expect to see OR in such a solution

Comment: @ RyanVincent & @PawelKosi After double-checking: I have updated my answer with a new sqlfiddle that is original data but using my (non-NOTed) inequalities allowing one-day overlap without self-conflict per the question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/32 If you then change the GTR date to 31st, there is one-day overlap but no self-conflict with Navara and the Navara has no conflicts and disappears. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee38/7  Your ineequalities need to be <= & >=. Then yours also exclude that case. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ee38/8

Comment: @Strawberry, I try to do easy to understand as the first answer - I am not too concerned about efficient? That comes later. I try and get useful answers via the more obvious queries.

Comment: @Strawberry It's just deMorgan applied to an AND.

Comment: @philipxy, we are on the same page - I like your approach - it makes sense. Give us time to catch up with you. :)

Answer (score 3):

For each input and output table find its *meaning*. Ie a statement template parameterized by column names, aka *predicate*, that a row makes into a true or false statement, aka *proposition*. A table holds the rows that make its predicate into a true proposition. Ie rows that make a true proposition go in a table and rows that make a false proposition stay out. Eg for your input table:

```
rental [tableid] was user [userid] renting car [car] from [from] to [to]
```

Then phrase the output table predicate in terms of the input table predicate. *Don't* use descriptions like your 1 & 2:

> 1. If any user has date overlaps in his car assignments of more than one day (end of the assignment can be on the same day as the new assignment start).

Instead find the predicate that an arbitrary row states when in the table:

```
rental [tableid] was user [user] renting car [car] from [from] to [to]
    in self-conflict with some other rental
```

For the DBMS to calculate the rows making this true we must express this in terms of our given predicate(s) plus literals & conditions:

```
-- query result holds the rows where
FOR SOME t2.tableid, t2.userid, ...:
    rental [t1.tableid] was user [t1.userid] renting car [t1.car] from [t1.from] to [t1.to]
AND rental [t2.tableid] was user [t2.userid] renting car [t2.car] from [t2.from] to [t2.to]
AND [t1.userid] = [t2.userid] -- userids id the same users
AND [t1.to] > [t2.from] AND ...  -- tos/froms id intervals with overlap more than one day
...
```

(Inside an SQL `SELECT` statement the cross product of `JOIN`ed tables has column names of the form *`alias`*`.`*`column`*. Think of `.` as another character allowed in column names. Finally the `SELECT` clause drops the *`alias`*`.`s.)

We convert a query predicate to an SQL query that calculates the rows that make it true:

- A table's predicate gets replaced by the table alias.
- To use the same predicate/table multiple times make aliases.
- Changing column *`old`* to *`new`* in a predicate adds `AND`*`old`*`=`*`new`*.
- `AND` of predicates gets replaced by `JOIN`.
- `OR` of predicates gets replaced by `UNION`.
- `AND NOT` of predicates gets replaced by `EXCEPT`, `MINUS` or appropriate `LEFT JOIN`.
- `AND`*`condition`* gets replaced by `WHERE` or `ON` *`condition`*.
- For a predicate true `FOR SOME`*`columns to drop`* or when `THERE EXISTS`*`columns to drop`*, `SELECT DISTINCT`*`columns to keep`*.
- Etc. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682228/how-to-get-matching-data-from-another-sql-table-for-two-different-columns-inner/27682724#27682724).)

[Hence](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af69b/34) (completing the ellipses):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM t t1 JOIN t t2
ON t1.userid = t1.userid -- userids id the same users
WHERE t1.to > t2.from AND t2.to > t1.from -- tos/froms id intervals with overlap more than one day
AND t1.tableid <> t2.tableid -- tableids id different rentals
```

> 2. Did any two users tried to get the same car assigned on the same date, or the date ranges overlap for them on the same car.

Finding the predicate that an arbitrary row states when in the table:

```
rental [tableid] was user [user] renting car [car] from [from] to [to]
    in conflict with some other user's rental
```

In terms of our given predicate(s) plus literals & conditions:

```
-- query result holds the rows where
FOR SOME t2.*
    rental [t1.tableid] was user [t1.userid] renting car [t1.car] from [t1.from] to [t1.to]
AND rental [t2.tableid] was user [t2.userid] renting car [t2.car] from [t2.from] to [t2.to]
AND [t1.userid] <> [t2.userid] -- userids id different users
AND [t1.car] = [t2.car] -- .cars id the same car
AND [t1.to] >= [t2.from] AND [t2.to] >= [t1.from] -- tos/froms id intervals with any overlap
AND [t1.tableid] <> [t2.tableid] -- tableids id different rentals
```

The `UNION` of queries for predicates 1 & 2 returns the rows for which *`predicate 1`*`OR`*`predicate 2`*.

Try to learn to express predicates--what rows state when in tables--if only as the goal for intuitive (sub)querying.

**PS** It is good to always have data checking edge & non-edge cases for a condition being true & being false. Eg try query 1 with GTR starting on the 31st, an overlap of only one day, which should *not* be a self-conflict.

**PPS** Querying involving duplicate rows, as with NULLs, has quite complex query meanings. It's hard to say when a tuple goes in or stays out of a table and how many times. For queries to have the simple intuitive meanings per my correspondences they can't have duplicates. Here SQL unfortunately differs from the relational model. In practice people rely on idioms when allowing non-distinct rows & they rely on rows being distinct because of constraints. Eg joining on UNIQUE columns per UNIQUEs, PKs & FKs. Eg: A final DISTINCT step is only doing work at a different time than a version that doesn't need it; time might or might not be be an important implementation issue affecting the phrasing chosen for a given predicate/result.

Comment: philipxy thank you for the answer, I am learning a lot at the moment and I need to get my head around your excellent reply. I will keep you posted on my progress. Thanks again!

Comment: philipxy I wish I could mark both answers! You have thought me a great deal in logic behind creating queries. Thank you very much!