# Database query issue, can someone help me fix this issue

Tags: database

```
 CREATE TABLE HotelStays
 (
     roomNum INTEGER NOT NULL,
     arrDate DATE NOT NULL,
     depDate DATE NOT NULL,
     guestName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (roomNum, arrDate)
);
```

ISSUE: a new entry (for a new guest) could be put in for a room number, even before the existing guest has checked out:

Comment: *What* database? Do you have a **constraint** that would prevent a reservation for a room that's already occupied?

Comment: Stopping overlaps is usually only enabled by the use of triggers. Post the type of database (looks a bit like SQL Server) and maybe we can help. How is the data currently added, and does it have the capability to manage errors thrown by the databsae

Comment: `(roomNum, depDate)` is also a candidatae key, ie UNIQUE NOT NULL here.

Comment: Re ISSUE: Are you trying to say that you want to know how to enforce the constraint that room bookings don't overlap improperly?

Answer (score -1):

If guests must check out before some time of day and check in after that time then it is ok to have a booking end on the same day as another one begins. That is why there is a checkout time and checkin time.

See [this question & its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34299714/3404097) for the kind of query that would check whether there would be a conflict in bookings. Ie whether two arrDate-to-depDate intervals overlap inappropriately. Ie whether they overlap by more than one day. You can query for conflicts in an trigger when you (try to) add a new booking.